# Textview Autolink -Phone- is not working if number length is 4 numbers

Tags: android, textview, autolink

I have a textview that use the following

android:autoLink="phone"

it is working fine if number length > 4 character, and didn't work otherwise, although there are some hot number that only 4 numbers

Thanks

Comment: will android:autoLink="all" suffice your requirement?

Comment: i have same same requirement. i have found that android >= 5.0 auto links numbers of 7-11 digits. which some times varies with different OEMs.

i have a working number which i use and its of 11 digits but it does not make it link able

Comment: I have solved it by adding on click listener and specify text color.